# Oracle 12c server cannot be accessed from remote computer using the .Net provider

Tags: oracle

On the Oracle server, I **can** connect using the following:

[image]

The status is the following:

[image]

When I try to connect from my developer computer using the .Net provider with these settings:

[image]

I **cannot** connect and get the following error:

[image]

I tried with sqlplus:

```
sqlplus system/password@http://10.111.111.47:1521/Telefon
```

> ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier
>   specified

This is my **listener.ora** file content:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Firewall is disabled.

What should I set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have the `http:` in the host name, in either place. The SQL*Plus version would be:

```
sqlplus system/password@//10.111.111.47:1521/Telefon
```

assuming the service name is the same as the SID, which isn't necessarily the case; from your `lsnrctl status` it is for you so that part should be OK.

But your listener is only listening on localhost, `127.0.0.1`. That means it is not contactable from anywhere else. You'll probably get a 'no listener' error with that connection string. You need to modify your listener configuration so it's listening on the external IP address, `10.111.111.47`, which is hopefully static and not assigned by DHCP.  It can listen on both addresses if necessary:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = AndrasWin7x64v1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

Assuming `AndrasWin7x64v1` resolves to `10.111.111.47`, at least within that server; if not you can use the IP address instead:

```
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.111.111.47)(PORT = 1521))
```

But again, you should only be using IP addresses if the server's IP is static; if it's dynamic (assigned by DHCP) then you should be using a DNS name that resolves to that address, in the `listener.ora` and from the client, and you should probably do that anyway even if it is static in case it has to change in the future.

Comment: I updated the initial post with my listener.ora content. Can you tell, what should I set to make it listen for external requests?