# Oracle database 12c networking between client and server machine using TNS

Tags: oracle

I followed the instructions in the link: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ONGz9czAikE
And got to the point of testing a Local Net Name Configuration(8:30) when i got to the point of preforming the test it seems like the window is stuck, same thing happens when i try to connect to the server db with Sql developer there i get a socket timeout error after waiting few minutes.
I'm trying to avoid downloading the oracle client software because of a company long security verification protocol.
What am i missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Depending on the server setup (RAC for example) the TNS protocol might sent a redirect to a different address (internal listener). Those redirecty sometime contain host names which are not known to clients. Try adding the RAC cluster node names to the hosts file on the client to avoid this problem. (the actual fix would be to configure it correctly on the server).

Comment: Can you ping the db hostname?

Comment: Solved it by using external IP instead of host name in listener.ora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:
[Oracle 12c server cannot be accessed from remote computer using the .Net provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676311/oracle-12c-server-cannot-be-accessed-from-remote-computer-using-the-net-provide)

Try using an external IP instead of hostname like so:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.30.50.90)(PORT = 1521))
     )
  )
```